# Large table cell wrapping in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a table in Word which is 5 columns wide and has multiple rows.  In Row 3, cells 1, 2, 3, and 5 have simple text.  Cell 4 contains a large quantity of text and therefore needs to wrap over several pages. Therefore, I mark "Allow row to break across pages."

Problem: On the next page where the row has wrapped, cells 1, 2, 3, and 5 are blank with cell 4 displaying the wrapped text.

Is there any way that I can get the simple text from row 3, cells 1, 2 and 3 to repeat on the pages which contain the wrapped text of cell 4?  I do not want the data to be in the table heading, as I have multiple rows with a similar volume of text.

Comment: Not even header row works properly in this way when the row is split across pages, I don't think you will find any solution to this question unfortunately, Microsoft Word just doesn't support that sort of thing.

Comment: What a shame.  Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be out of luck on this one.  I know exactly what you're talking about, but I don't think this functionality exists.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I was doubtful, but slightly hopeful that it may have been possible.  Looks like I will need to format it manually.  Thanks again for your time.